# error: Could not find any of the FFTW libraries (Windows)

Tags: python, pip, pyfftw

I want to install pyFFTW but pycharm termial shows me some errors like below.

I tried `pip install pyFFTW` and got messages :

```
Collecting pyFFTW
  Using cached pyFFTW-0.12.0.tar.gz (137 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.10 in c:\flask_server\venv\lib\site-packages (from pyFFTW) (1.21.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyFFTW
  Building wheel for pyFFTW (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\flask_server\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rg4d72bl\\pyfftw_08beecb75b3d4e24b84893cb10e0b2c2\\setup.py'"'"'
; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rg4d72bl\\pyfftw_08beecb75b3d4e24b84893cb10e0b2c2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'f
rom setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-falexgv8'
       cwd: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rg4d72bl\pyfftw_08beecb75b3d4e24b84893cb10e0b2c2\
  Complete output (25 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw
  copying pyfftw\config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw
  copying pyfftw\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw
  copying pyfftw\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw\builders
  copying pyfftw\builders\builders.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw\builders
  copying pyfftw\builders\_utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw\builders
  copying pyfftw\builders\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw\builders
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw\interfaces
  copying pyfftw\interfaces\cache.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw\interfaces
  copying pyfftw\interfaces\dask_fft.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw\interfaces
  copying pyfftw\interfaces\numpy_fft.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw\interfaces
  copying pyfftw\interfaces\scipy_fft.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw\interfaces
  copying pyfftw\interfaces\scipy_fftpack.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw\interfaces
  copying pyfftw\interfaces\_utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw\interfaces
  copying pyfftw\interfaces\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw\interfaces
  UPDATING build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw/_version.py
  set build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw/_version.py to '0.12.0'
  running build_ext
  error: Could not find any of the FFTW libraries
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyFFTW
  Running setup.py clean for pyFFTW
Failed to build pyFFTW
Installing collected packages: pyFFTW
    Running setup.py install for pyFFTW ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\flask_server\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rg4d72bl\\pyfftw_08beecb75b3d4e24b84893cb10e0b2c2\\setup.py'"'
"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rg4d72bl\\pyfftw_08beecb75b3d4e24b84893cb10e0b2c2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"
'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zstugs1k\install-re
cord.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\flask_server\venv\include\site\python3.8\pyFFTW'
         cwd: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rg4d72bl\pyfftw_08beecb75b3d4e24b84893cb10e0b2c2\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    UPDATING build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw/_version.py
    set build\lib.win32-3.8\pyfftw/_version.py to '0.12.0'
    running build_ext
    error: Could not find any of the FFTW libraries
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\flask_server\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rg4d72bl\\pyfftw_08beecb75b3d
4e24b84893cb10e0b2c2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rg4d72bl\\pyfftw_08beecb75b3d4e24b84893cb10e0b2c2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exist
s(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Te
mp\pip-record-zstugs1k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\flask_server\venv\include\site\python3.8\pyFFTW' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried several solutions from google and stackoverflow, such as

```
    pip install wheel
    pip install pyFFTW-0.12.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

with pyFFTW-0.12.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl file in current working directory.

but terminal shows me error like **ERROR: pyFFTW-0.12.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.**

I installed numpy, scipy, cython and pytest already.
My python version is 3.8.3 and I don't know why these doesn't work.

Please give me some advice and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you running 32-bit something (python most likely)?

Comment: [pyFFTW](https://pypi.org/project/pyFFTW/) is a pythonic wrapper around FFTW library. To use pyFFTW first you must [install FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html).